# Remote desktop connection breaks when vmware machine is powered on

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, vmware-player

On a remote server (Windows Server 2012) we have **vmware player** (v. 6.0.3) installed. We can connect to the server using **remote desktop** without any problem. But when you're connected and have powered on the virtual machine on the server the remote desktop connection breaks immediately. Latter attempts to connect to it fail.

What might be the cause of that?

Comment: How do you have the guest networking set up? It could be that causing it to break.

Comment: `On a remote server (Windows Server 2012) we have vmware player (v. 6.0.3) installed` - I'm sorry. That's just wrong. Why aren't you using the Hyper-V role on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If the guest network is currently NAT, switch to bridged.

Confirm the guest and/or VMware are not listening for RDP on the same address as the host, thereby stealing the port.